# after switching to a different display server I can't even turn off my laptop

Tags: boot

The reason I changed it was because I had an infinite login loop when I tried to login to Ubuntu with the awesome VM, the same thing happened with the normal Ubuntu option. What did work was Ubuntu on waylans option. I went searching and saw a few websites for fixes, tried all of them but none of them worked. There was a "last resort" option listed and I tried it. I went ahead and rebooted my laptop to test if it was fixed but instead everything went wrong and I can't do anything.

I tried to reinstall Ubuntu from a live USB I had but it instead caused it so that I have 0 control and can't turn my laptop off.

FYI: the infinite login loop is when I enter the correct password, then the screen flashes and brings me back to the screen to select a user to login. I enter the correct password and the same thing happens again.

Comment: It is unclear what you did or why.

Comment: I switched to the awesome VM and I saw one of the fixes as a last resort I'm not sure what I switched it to, but then this happened. The issue was that I couldn't login to Ubuntu or awesome I can only login with Ubuntu on Wayland option. If I chose anything else it would loop infinitely in a login loop.

Comment: Please include that info in the question with the edit function.

Comment: Done I added more info

Comment: I fixed it by just waiting for the laptop to die then reinstalling it. I'm not gonna mess with another VM for a wihle.